# Nested if statement in if else

Tags: javascript, if-statement

```
if (document.URL.indexOf("google") != -1) {
    alert('at google');
}
else if (document.URL.indexOf("yahoo") != -1) {
    if(a === true){
        alert("true");
    if(b === false)
        alert("false");
}
```

I am having a hard time understanding nesting in Yahoo's code. Is this possible?

Comment: You can have as many `nested if` inside an outer `if` as you want, if only the logic allows, which rarely does. Your code is not clear and have not been copied properly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is entirely possible.
If `document.URL.indexOf("google") != -1`, it will alert 'at google'
If `document.URL.indexOf("yahoo") != -1` **and** `a === true`, then it will alert 'true'
If `document.URL.indexOf("yahoo") != -1` **but** `b === false`, then it will alert 'false'